# Как сбросить/обновить кэш браузера? (Angular)

Tags: изображения, angular, кэширование, браузер, frontend

У меня есть пользователи с аватарками, которые я получаю со своего сервера по URL.
На сервере я указываю в заголовке следующие:

```
Cache-Control: no-transform, public, max-age=86400
```

Когда пользователь меняет аватарку, URL для загрузки остается таким же, а в кэше остается старая аватарка.

Подскажите, есть ли способ программно сбросить кэш в браузере, или другие решения этой проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно к адресу добавляют параметр запроса, меняющийся при обновлении файла. Формально можно назвать его версией файла, и при изменении версии кэш обновляется.

```
this.imageSrc="/profile_pic/profile_pic.png?12345"
```